# How to match a column of string in a column of lines in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**1st column**:

```
*packed decimal(18,2) chd_ytd_rtck_chg_am;
packed decimal(18,2) chd_ytd_deah_chg_am;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_late_ct;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_ovlm_ct,chd_ytd_test;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_deah_ct;
packed decimal(12,0) chd_ytd_rtck_ct;*
```

**2nd column**:

```
*chd_ytd_late_ct
chd_ytd_test
chd_ytd_rtck_ct


chd_ytd_rtck_chg_am*
```

If the string in 2nd column exists in 1st column then **3rd Column** should show **true**.
Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B1&";",A$1:A$6)))>0
```

I used the concatenation to prevent any possibility of it being a substring. Also, in case you got Excel O365, just use `SUM()`.

---

To answer you updated question, you could use:

```
=IF(B1<>"",SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B1&";",A$1:A$6)))>0,"")
```

[image]

Comment: You are my savior. Thank you so much. Can u also please share some knowledge of this formula?

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @ShankarMG, I think the updated answer would work for you. Check it pls.

Comment: I can still use your 1st answer to my problem. Thank you so much, my friend.

Comment: btw in the second answer, you missed ", ytd_chd_test" A4 value.

Comment: ahhh, I see what it is you are trying now. Try: `=IF(B1<>"",SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B1&";",SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A$6,","," "))))>0,"")`

Comment: need your help. To reverse the search i.e. if the 3rd string in the column A matches the string in the column B, then it should return true